# Setting the size of a matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a matplotlib figure in a loop.
Each subplot should have a size of width `w` and height `h`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

some_list_with_information= [item for item in range(10)]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(some_list_with_information), 2)
for index,item in enumerate(some_list_with_information):
    axs[index, 0].plot(x, y)
    axs[index, 0].set_title('Axis [0, 0]')
    
    axs[index, 1].plot(x, y, 'tab:orange')
    axs[index, 1].set_title('Axis [0, 1]')
```

I tried several things like  `axs[index, 0].set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)` but it is not working.

Since I don't know, how long the list `some_list_with_information` is going to be, I would like to **set the size of each subplot**, such that each new plot is appended.

Is that possible, or is `fig` a static object, that needs to be created at the beginning with its final size?

Comment: View this tutorial on [gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) and you will have not problem managing subplots

Comment: I suggest using the standard way with `figsize=`: `plt.subplots(len(some_list_with_information), 2, figsize=(w, h))` and use `len(some_list_with_information) x h` for the height. (e.g. multiply the desired height of each subplot, by the length).

Comment: I think https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ Is designed to do what you want with minimal fuss.